# A non-intrusive way to modify one attribute of the link defined in a function

Tags: org-mode, org-link, org-ref

The following code from `org-ref` defines a citation link:

```
(defun org-ref-define-citation-link (type &optional key)
  "Add a citation link of TYPE for `org-ref'.
With optional KEY, set the reftex binding.  For example:
\(org-ref-define-citation-link \"citez\" ?z) will create a new
citez link, with reftex key of z, and the completion function."
  (interactive "sCitation Type: \ncKey: ")

  ;; create the formatting function
  (eval `(org-ref-make-format-function ,type))

  (eval
   `(if (fboundp 'org-link-set-parameters)
    (org-link-set-parameters
     ,type
     :follow (lambda (_path) (funcall org-ref-cite-onclick-function nil))
     :export (quote ,(intern (format "org-ref-format-%s" type)))
     :complete (quote ,(intern (format "org-%s-complete-link" type)))
     :help-echo (lambda (window object position)
              (when org-ref-show-citation-on-enter
            (save-excursion
              (goto-char position)
              ;; Here we wrap the citation string to a reasonable size.
              (let ((s (org-ref-format-entry
                    (org-ref-get-bibtex-key-under-cursor))))
                (with-temp-buffer
                  (insert s)
                  (fill-paragraph)
                  (buffer-string))))))
     :face 'org-ref-cite-face
     :display 'full
     :keymap org-ref-cite-keymap)
      (org-add-link-type
       ,type
       (lambda (_path) (funcall org-ref-cite-onclick-function nil))
       (quote ,(intern (format "org-ref-format-%s" type))))))
```

Is there a non-intrusive way to modify only the `:export` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, but you have to do it for each link. Assuming you are using org 9, you can do it like this in an init file, or in an elisp src block in your org-file:

```
(org-link-set-parameters "cite" :export 'some-new-export-function)
```